# How to append to the existing document without replacing earlier while uploading to couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

I have an array of json Like

[{json1},{json2},...] 
At first step will upload first json document and then in subsequent steps will have to get this jsondocument from couchbase and append json2 to it (without replacing it) and upload again . Have tried using jsonarray but it is not possible with upsert.
what is the correct way to do this .

Comment: Can you please add a sample code of what you have tried already?

Comment: Sounds like you need the arrayAppend subdocument operation! https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/subdocument-operations.html#array-append-and-prepend

Comment: We're going to need more information to be useful, here.  Arrays and upsert will work.  How is it failing for you?

Comment: @GrahamPople Thanks for the share , though it was for SubarrayDocument update and I need Full document update so the following worked for me : DataSource.getBucket().mutateIn(couchKeyId).arrayInsert("["+size+"]", jsonStr).execute();

Comment: @priya I'm somewhat confused as you are doing a Sub-Document operation there with mutateIn.  What you've put there is basically what I was getting at with the doc link.  arrayAppend seems more what you asked for originally than arrayInsert, but whatever works best for your use case.